# Irregular behaivour of URL Link - Multiple pages webscraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am writing a Python code to get data from a sharepoint website using Beautiful Soup.

Each page has 10 rows of details. So I should be collecting all the links up to the last page and then get the entire list of data I need.

Issues

1. When I am trying to open the page2 urllink Using Python code, it is still opening the page1 (base url) link.
2. When I open the base url from browser (page1) link and from there using next button, I am able to navigate to page2. But the same when I open a new tab and directly copy paste the page2 link, it refreshes and opens and page1 (base url) link.

Code:

```py
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

session = requests.Session()

session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('username','password')

r = session.get("UrlLinkOfPage2")

print(r.status_code)

print(r.content)
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL format of the site you're scraping?

Comment: It is client specific private Url cannot be shared.

Comment: I don't want the exact URL, but I want to know how does it navigate to next pages? Does it append `?page=2` to URL or something alike.

Comment: page1 baseurl : http://data.twister.com/sites/Falcione%20Needed%20View.aspx=ShowInGrid%3DTrue

page2 url (After clicking the next option ) http://data.twister.com/sites/Falcione%20Needed%20View.aspx=Paged%3DTRUE-PagedPrev%3DTRUE-p_Title%3DCCC2-p_ID%3D151-ShowInGrid%3DTrue-PageFirstRow%3D31

Comment: I once had visited a site where identified me by cookie and I had some similar issue, so first I used `session.get()` to get the home page of that site and get my cookies set and then navigated to other parts, give it a try (before `session.get(page2)` use `session.get(home_page)`.

Comment: I tried the above ( session.get(page1) and then session.get(page2) but still only page1 results are being displayed for page2 as well.

Comment: Assuming you're on chrome, open the site in your browser, open developer options, go to network tab, check `Preserve log`, and then click the button for loading page 2, then check from which request the content is actually coming from.

Comment: I have done the above. The link was slight different from the original one which I copied from browser url. But when the try the link of preservelog with session.get and in browser as well, it is returning 403 error.

Comment: I am very new to Python Scripting , so please do consider this and help me out.

Comment: One possible cause is that you're not sending all the required headers in python, which your browser send, so send all the headers which your browser send to request the second page.

Comment: Can you ping the sample piece of code?

Comment: Make a **dictionary** of all the headers your browser is sending for the second page and then use `session.get(url, headers=your_headers_dictionary)`.

Comment: After adding the headers , it is working as expected. Thankyou so much.

Comment: Happy coding  :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with some websites is that they are expecting some special headers to be sent, so open the site home page in your browser (login if required), open the *network* tab in *developer tools* and inspect the request your browser make to access the second page. Then copy all the headers it is sending and make a dictionary in your python code containing those headers like:

```py
my_headers = {
    'some-header': value,
    'another-header': another-value
}
```

then use *requests* library to send those headers when requesting the page like:

```py
response = session.get(second_page_url, headers=my_headers)
```

Comment: I am unable to accept the above as Answer. And I am new to Stack Overflow as well. When I try to upvote it says : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.